# Nested list failed to convert from markdown or html to pdf

Tags: html, pandoc, markdown

I am trying to convert `markdown` to `pdf` using `pandoc` with the latex-engine set as `xelatex` because I am trying to use fonts installed on my system. I have tried switching the `pdf-engine` to `pdflatex` but the problem persists.

I pasted this snippet of markdown into the **Pandoc Try Online** demo:

```
###Lipsum
  + **Lipsum Generator (Sept 2013-Present)**

   **[google](https://www.google.com/)**

   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged

    * Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

    * Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance
```

The rendered latex:

```
\subsubsection{Lipsum}\label{lipsum}

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  \textbf{Lipsum Generator (Sept 2013-Present)}
\end{itemize}

\textbf{\href{https://www.google.com/}{google}}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
essentially unchanged

\begin{verbatim}
* Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

* Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance
\end{verbatim}
```

> I have noticed that  `\begin{verbatim}` instead of `\begin{itemize}` which I presume is causing the error.

I used this command:

```
pandoc resume.md --standalone --latex-engine=xelatex -f markdown --atx-headers -t latex -o resume_pandoc.pdf -V mainfont=Ubuntu -V sansfont=Lato -V fontsize=11pt -V title="Vamsi Deepak Ampolu" -V papersize=letter
```

I also tried converting the `html` to `pdf` using this command

```
pandoc resume.html --standalone --latex-engine=xelatex -V mainfont=Ubuntu -V sansfont=Lato -V papersize=letter title="Vamsi Deepak Ampolu"
```

> However, I have found that nested lists which render correctly in `html` render like this in the `pdf` output:

```
+ built a layer of dynamic, reusable UI templates using Handlebars based on Twitter Bootstrap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to indent exactly four (4) spaces for each level.

Input:

```
### Lipsum
+ **Lipsum Generator (Sept 2013-Present)**

    **[google](https://www.google.com/)**

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged

    * Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

    * Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance
```

Output:

```
\subsubsection{Lipsum}\label{lipsum}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  \textbf{Lipsum Generator (Sept 2013-Present)}

  \textbf{\href{https://www.google.com/}{google}}

  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
  since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
  scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
  five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
    It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
    making it over 2000 years old.
  \item
    Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of ``de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum'' (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
    written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics,
    very popular during the Renaissance
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: does pandoc support the use of html `center` tag within the markdown?